# Is there a way to return a float from int variables in c++ functions?

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

My program is returning a value of the score array instead of the average. I am guessing the problem has to do with the type conversions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float average(int length, int array[]);

int main(){
    int N;
    
    cout << "Enter length: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << endl;
    int scores[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << "Enter score: ";
        cin >> scores[i];
    }
    
    cout << average(N, scores);
    return 0;   
}

float average(int length, int array[]){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        sum += array[i];
    }
    
    return (sum / length);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described the problem you are facing. At first glance I'm assuming your issue is that you are losing the fractional part due to `sum / length` being an integer

Comment: On a side note: `int N; ... int scores[N];` is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you divide the integer `sum` by the integer `length`, you get an integer result. The fact that you store it in a `float` doesn't change that.

You probably want:

```
return (static_cast<float>(sum) / static_cast<float>(length));
```

Comment: Re ”if they also took into account how you used the result, they'd be incomprehensible”: `int x = f;` and `float x = f;` produce different values if `f` is defined as `foo f;` where `foo` is `struct foo { operator int() { return 3; } operator float() { return 4; } };`.